# Angular 6 Module Not importing correctly

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an `app.module` where it imports `LazyLoaderModule`.

my lazy loader module is as follows.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [   
    {path: 'auth', loadChildren: '../auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
    {path: 'login', loadChildren: '../login/login.module#LoginModule'},
    {path: '*', redirectTo: 'login'},
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LazyLoadModule { }
```

In my lazyloader router I have the routes as follows

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from '../../Components/auth/auth.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '', component: AuthComponent, children: [
        { path: 'orders', loadChildren: '../orders/orders.module#OrdersModule' },
        { path: 'tables', loadChildren: '../../tables/tables.module#TablesModule' },
        { path: 'guarded-routes', loadChildren: '../../guarded-routes/guarded-routes.module#GuardedRoutesModule' },
        { path: 'maps', loadChildren: '../../maps/maps.module#MapsModule' },

    ]
}];
```

I want to import a new Module

`import { MomentModule } from 'ngx-moment';` in the `AppModule` to be imported in `the OrdersModule`

however, when I import in the app module I get an error.

BUT when I import in the orders module it works.

my goal is to use the MomentModule in the whole app and not just the ordersModule.

Comment: For these use cases you should be importing this into a shared module that is imported in each lazy loaded module that needs it I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to handle this would be, import the MomentModule in a SharedModule and export it.

Something like,

```
import {MomentModule} from 'ngx-moment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MomentModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MomentModule
  ]
})
```

and use it in the app.module as

```
SharedModule.forRoot()
```

Comment: you chould look into the sample https://github.com/amv-networks/amv-ts-demo-app/blob/6176ab1a2472eda658819a0cc90f437ccc9b21a7/src/app/app.module.ts